# Tracing the execution of a java program running on a remote *nix machine

Tags: java, debugging, exception

I am trying to debug a program running on a remote solaris machine.
I wanted to know path taken by the program during the execution just like stake trace
like

```
Class A.method1 called method2 in class B
Class B.method2 called method3 in class C
..
...
Control returned from method2 in class B to
method1 in Class A etc
```

We cannot run the program from eclipse since the environment cannot be reproduced since it is a large enterprise level system having many upstream and downstream systems.

I suspect somewhere in the program there is an exception being thrown and that is not handled properly like a empty catch block/not logging or rethrowing the exception.

What is the best way to debug such programs. Please help me with your solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, your remote machine runs under Solaris you could use DTrace to dynamically add probes to your running JVMs and the complete system.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Eclipse to debug remote applications, all you need to do is add a few startup parameters: http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/how-debug-remote-java-applicat

Comment: I don't have the complete source of the application. We have only the code of the modules which we work on, In that case will this work?

Comment: Yup, it should. You normally don't have the source code for all classes anyway; for example, `src.zip` doesn't include source for `sun.*` classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug remotely with eclipse, see [this](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53459.html)

Comment: I don't have the complete source of the application. We have only the code of the modules which we work on, In that case will this work?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trace the execution of your Java code you can use a tool called [InTrace](http://mchr3k.github.com/org.intrace/).

InTrace supports outputting the trace from a Java program to disk or over the network to the InTrace UI. This should be ideal for debugging your Java program on a remote solaris machine.

NOTE: InTrace is a free and open source tool which I have written.

Answer (score 0):

You could remote debug, which Eclipse supports, but may not be permitted by the system admin. The only other thing I can think of is lots and lots of logging

Answer (score 0):

in such cases I have used Btrace https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-btrace , it doesn't require you to setup a remote debugger, nor to have the source code of your Java application.

Another way is to run jdb https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html  and attach to the process - but you must enable the process JVM to use jdwp -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_shmem,server=y,suspend=n

In general I agree that the JDK is lacking a professional built-in tracing/debugging tool